# How are re-roll credits earned?

Tags: league-of-legends

In the ARAM queue that arrived with the Freljord patch you can re-roll a champion you've been given by using a re-roll credit. How fast do you accrue these re-rolls? Is it based on number of games played or number of champions owned?

Comment: Oh I didn't hear about that. Seems great ! Interesting question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Reroll Mechanics

You gain Reroll points based on games played and champions owned.  Once you've saved up 250 Reroll points, it grants you 1 Reroll, which is used to perform a Reroll in ARAM.  You can only have 2 Rerolls saved up; When you have 2 Rerolls, you no cannot accrue Reroll points.

The formula for Reroll points gained is `30 + (1 x Champions Owned)` per game.  This has been [stated in the forums by a developer](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=36615202#36615202), and is very easy to confirm in the post-game stats by mousing over the Reroll point awards.

#### Standard 30 Points

[image: base points]
[image]

#### Bonus From Champions Owned

Note that I own 58 champions.

[image: champion bonus points]
[image]

Comment: It says in your answer that it is 250 reroll points, but in the quote from Brackhar it specifies 200. Was that a transcription error?

Comment: It was 200 initially on the PBE;  they changed it to 250 for live, but neglected to update the patch notes.  If you hover over your Reroll credits in your profile page, it says 0/250 if you have zero points.

Answer (score 5):

From the Patch Notes:

> Players may reroll for a different champion in Champion Select for 200 reroll points.
>    All players have been credited with 200 reroll points.
>    Additional reroll points are gained by completing matchmade Howling Abyss games.
>    Reroll point gains increase based on the number of champions the player owns.
>    Reroll point count can be checked in the player profile.

The only mention of the formula that I've come across is that a finished game nets you 30+Champions points, from [here](http://www.rtsguru.com/game/435/article/5575/LoL-PBE-Rerolls-for-ARAM-Queue.html) but I'm not sure how reliable it is.